# 'Distinct' entries only to create a sitemap.xml file using Django (1.5.4)

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I'm trying to output a sitemap.xml file within Django and have been successfully doing so as per the following.

```
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/day/AAA</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/day/AAA</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/day/BBB</loc>
</url>
```

...etc

However, as you will see from my attached sitemaps file, I am trying to only return the distinct 'name' field as each addition for every subdomain, within my database, this 'name' field is often repeated, but I only want it once each time in the sitemap. Currently trying to do so via Django's '.disctint()' to seemingly return a list of dictionaries and so it should look something like:

```
<loc>http://example.com/day/AAA</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/day/BBB</loc>
</url>
```

...etc

However, it's currently being returned like:

```
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/day/AAA</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/day/AAA</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/day/AAA</loc>
</url>
```

etc... on and on, only the first 'name' each time..

My Current sitemaps.py file is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
import datetime
from fruit.models import fruitmodel
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db.models import Sum

class fruitSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names

    def items(self):
        return fruitmodel.objects.all()


    def location(self, obj):

        dict =  fruitmodel.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct() 
        for i in dict:
                return '/day/%s' % i
        #return '/day/%s' % obj.name """ Current 'working' option, without distinct """
```

My Model is as per follows:

```
class fruitmodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField()
    veggeorfruit = models.CharField(default="vegetable", max_length=128, unique=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Anything you have to add would be appreciated. Huge thanks in advance :)

As requested:
mocking up a print statement (printer.py)

```
from fruit.models import fruitmodel

print( fruitmodels.objects.order_by('name').values_list('name', flat=True).distinct().query)
```

gives
" django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings. "

Comment: Have you set `ordering` in the `Meta` attributes of `fruitmodel`?

Comment: No, I haven't specified this, by default it looks like it returns them in order they were placed into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `items` method, not your `location` method. The `items` method is what generates the list of items in the site map, the `location` method is just supposed to return one location given the one item it is passed as its `obj` parameter.

So try this:

```
def items(self):
    return fruitmodel.objects.distinct('name')

def location(self, obj):
    return '/day/%s' % obj.name
```

Edit: the above seems to work only in PostgreSQL (I think). For databases that don't support `DISTINCT ON`, you could try:

```
def items(self):
    return list(set([f.name for f in fruitmodel.objects.all()]))

def location(self, obj):
    return '/day/%s' % obj
```

But I think a better solution would be to factor your model so that `name` is actually unique, and have the dates as related objects.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Hhhm, really interesting. Okay firstly, I needed to remove ', flat=True' to get past the debugging screen. It did give me a usuable sitemap, however, it was like:                       <loc>http://example.com/day/BBB</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://example.com/day/BBB</loc>
</url>
<url>  ... Etc

Comment: Tried again, with the full code as per Andrew's kind suggestion and can confirm having 'flat=True' in the code, does work, and isn't necessary to remove in this instance. However, it for some perplexing reason only gives one result over and over again, albeit a different one than before.

Comment: What do you mean "get past the debugging screen"? Were you getting an error? What was it?

Comment: Also could you edit your question to include the model?

Comment: I hadn't fully written as per your suggestion :/ (only put in one 'name') Django's debugging said: "order_by() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flat'"

Comment: Oh ok, so you were passing `flat=True` to `order_by` instead of to `values_list`? Is it working now?

Comment: ^Exactly :) (Silly me!) Nope, sadly its just giving me the result BBB, BBB, BBB etc as opposed to AAA, BBB, CCC etc (before it was AAA, AAA, AAA...)

Comment: Could you include the output of `print( fruitmodel.objects.order_by('name').values_list('name', flat=True).distinct() .query)` in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72709/discussion-between-andrew-magee-and-wajw).